# Is it wrong to have the input shape as a sum of number of features and labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I try to make a regression and I have 3 features and 1 label (they all have 190 entries). I used at first `input_shape=[len(dataset.keys())]`, which is 4 and the results are very good.

Now I've realized that I should have written input_shape=`[len(training_dataset.keys())]`, which is 3 and tried many combinations of layers of different sizes and activation functions, to find the best model.

```py
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='elu', input_shape=[len(dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model
```

The results are awful (mean error rate used to be 156 and now is above 4500). So can I let it be like it was in the beginning or is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of your dataset, there are better ways to feed the amount of columns. The easiest and most straightforward (for me at least) is:

```
Dense(12, activation='relu', input_dim=training_dataset.shape[1])
```

That will help you in case your dataset is a Numpy array or a Pandas dataframe.

However, since you're using a function for building the model, I'd encourage you to make it like

```py
def build_model(input_dim):
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=input_dim),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model
```

So you can modify it and use it regardless of the scope of the dataset (suppose you want to build another model with that same function, it wouldn't work since it was linked to just one dataset).

As for the performance drop, my bet is that you were including the labels as part of the training dataset (it has happened to me before) and that created a "perfect" model. May be the error is on the activation function for the last layer or something like that, but I wouldn't say it has to do with that shape.

Edit: I thought it was a Classification task.

Comment: thank you very much for your response! why do you see it as a Classification? the output layer has to be a number (number of days to construct a product, there are no classes or something)
I need to train a model, so I can use new features without labels and try to predict them. Is using the model trained with labels in this situation wrong?

Comment: Oh well, there's the first catch then. I saw it as Classification because the last layer doesn't have a `linear` activation, the one you usually use for that task. The labels (being usually the names of the X side of the function) really don't matter. When you feed the data, all the model sees are the values store in the X. Making it flexible (not depend on specific names or labels) is a good idea, so you can retrain it later.

Comment: sorry to ask so many questions, I am alone in this and tried to learn from different sites. I still don't understand if it was wrong or right to let the labels in the training data in the beginning. If it is ok, like it is a sort of supervised learning, then I won't need to start the whole calculations from the beginning. would it work in the future to predict the labels of new features?